# Stop processing sourced file and continue

Tags: bash, shell, coding-style

When writing bash that sources another file, sometimes I want to skip processing if some conditions are true. For now, I've been either:

1. Wrapping the entire sub file in nested if statements
2. Wrapping the call to the source file in nested if statements

Both of these strategies have some drawbacks. It'd be so much better if I could write my scripts with this code style:

**main.sh**

```
echo "before"
. other
echo "after"
```

**other.sh**

```
# guard
if true; then
  # !! return to main somehow
fi
if true; then
  # !! return to main somehow
fi

# commands
echo "should never get here"
```

Is there a way to do this so that the `echo "after"` line in **main** gets called?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you could `return`:

```
if true; then
  return
fi
```

Quoting `help return`:

> `return: return [n]`
>
> > Return from a shell function.
> >
> > Causes a function or sourced script to exit with the return value
> >        specified by N.  If N is omitted, the return status is that of the
> >        last command executed within the function or script.
> >
> > Exit Status:
> >        Returns N, or failure if the shell is not executing a function or script.

Comment: No way! I don't know why I assumed that wouldn't do anything (since that's the typical pattern in other languages). My life is complete again.

Comment: @thedeeno It does!  And it's designed for this: _causes a function or sourced script_ ...